# sum two difrrent value from single table and subtract its value and group them by pcode

Tags: php, mysql

i have 1 table named rsales. and let say for example i have this following values from my table "rsales"

```
id | total | discount |  profit | remarks | p_code |
 1 |  20   |   2      |    5    |  sales  |  1234  |
 2 |  20   |   4      |   10    |  sales  |  1234  |
 3 |  20   |   6      |   15    |  sales  |  1234  | 
 5 |  20   |   2      |    5    |  return |  1234  |
 6 |  20   |   4      |   10    |  return |  1234  |
 7 |  10   |   5      |    5    |  sales  |  3333  |
 8 |  10   |   5      |    5    |  sales  |  3333  |
 9 |  10   |   5      |    5    |  sales  |  3333  |
10 |  10   |   5      |    5    |  return |  3333  |
11 |  10   |   5      |    5    |  return |  3333  |
```

my problem is that i want to sum all values where remarks = "sales" and sum all values where remarks = "return" and then after getting its sum i want to subtract total sum where remarks = 'sales' to total sum where remarks = 'return' and group them by pcode. so the following output must be something like this.

```
 | total | discount |  profit |  p_code |
 |  20   |   6      |   15    |   1234  |
 |  10   |   5      |   5     |   3333  |
```

i have this ff code but it can only sum values where remarks = 'return'

```
$result1 = mysql_query ("SELECT sum(total)  as tot,sum(discount) as dis, sum(profit) as prof   FROM rsales WHERE remarks ='return' GROUP by p_code ");
```

Comment: Review your table design if you can. It would be much easier to do calculations, if your sales are positive numbers and returns negative numbers. In such were the case you could do a simple sum. I have a DB with a similar pattern as yours, and it is just a nightmare to get correct statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need conditional summation.  Assuming that `remarks` only takes on the values of "sales" and "returns", then the following is a relatively simple way to do this:

```
SELECT sum(case when remarks = 'sales' then total else - total end) as tot,
       sum(case when remarks = 'sales' then discount else - discount end) as discount,
       sum(case when remarks = 'sales' then profit else - profit end) as profit,
       p_code 
FROM rsales
GROUP by p_code;
```